# FQL Get all of my friends' checkins?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

This seems to be impossible as of now .. can anyone give me a suitable query or a set of queries that can do this? Basically, I need ALL my friends' checkins: Ones they've checked in by themselves, Ones in which they've checked with a picture, Ones in which a user who is not my friend tagged them in.

My first attempt was this:

`SELECT checkin_id, author_uid, page_id, coords, tagged_uids, timestamp FROM checkin WHERE (author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) OR author_uid=me()) ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 50`

But this doesn't include checkins with pictures.

My second attempt was this:

`SELECT id, author_uid, app_id, timestamp, tagged_uids, page_id, page_type, coords, type FROM location_post
WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())`

But like the WHERE clause suggests, we're only looking for checkins which were created by a friend, but not ones in which my friends are tagged.

My next attempt was this:

`SELECT id, author_uid, app_id, timestamp, tagged_uids, page_id, page_type, coords, type FROM location_post
WHERE tagged_uids IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())`

But it just returns an empty data set as it probably should.

So short of submitting 500 odd queries, one for each of my friends, is there a way to do this?

Any pointers are much appreciated!

Thanks, 
Teja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this need to be in FQL or would the Graph API not suffice for this?

`/me/friends?fields=checkins`, although very slow (warning: with lots of friends this could timeout completely), returns me a list of my friends with an array of their recent checkins (and those checkins' likes, comments, etc)

You could also break it up into batches of friends for better performance:

`/?fields=checkins&ids=[CSV LIST OF FRIENDS TO CHECK]`

Comment: Hi, I'm very new to the API, so I didn't know this was an option. I've just tried this out, but I'm hitting some rate limit of 600 requests / 600 seconds very quickly (every 2-3 requests). I'm guessing even though I'm submitting a single request, somehow they're being treated as separate requests for each friend internally? And AFAIK, these are per app limits and not just per user limits. Is there any way to work around these?

Comment: The limits are per user session (i.e per access token) - a call for all friends' data should be treated as a single call as far as i know, but there are also CPU usage limits which are harder to plan for - if you're hitting these it'll be mentioned in your app insights

Answer (score 1):

we can also use following FQL to get friends checkins and checkins in which friends are tagged:

```
SELECT checkin_id FROM checkin WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) OR tagged_uids IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Answer (score 0):

I was recently trying to solve the same problem and finding that using the graph via /me/friends?fields=checkins was too slow to be usable and sometimes times out completely.

I did just stumble across the search function though, which seems to do exactly what I (and perhaps you) want.

To quote the facebook documentation:

> Checkins: https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=checkin (This request
>   returns you or your friend's latest checkins, or checkins where you or
>   your friends have been tagged; currently, it does not accept a q=
>   parameter.)

There's tons more examples here under Search:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/